# change /etc/localtime to UTC time?

Tags: terminal, filesystem

I noticed it is common for programming languages to utilize /etc/localtime when determining the current time to display for a user. In particular, I know that Ruby relies on /etc/localtime if the "TZ" environment variable is not set. I am able to read the contents of this binary like so:

```
$ zdump /etc/localtime
/etc/localtime  Sun Aug 12 16:53:50 2018 EDT
```

It seems, therefore, the time used by programming languages is Eastern Time North America. It makes sense, I am in the East Coast of the US. However, how can I change this file to UTC so that the programming language and software on my computer uses UTC rather than EDT time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the time in System Preferences, and that time should be reflected back in /etc/localtime.

If you want to do it at the command line, use the `systemsetup` tool (which has to be run via `sudo`, fyi).

Here are the relevant commands from `sudo systemsetup -help`:

```
Usage: systemsetup -gettimezone
    Display current time zone.

Usage: systemsetup -settimezone <timezone>
    Set current time zone to <timezone>. Use "-listtimezones" to list time zones.

Usage: systemsetup -listtimezones
    List time zones supported by this machine.
```